# How to access the difference member for merged interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider we have two interface `A` and `B`, how can I get the difference member for merged interface?

```js
interface A {
    from: string,
    items: number[],
}

interface B {
    to: string,
    items: number[],
}

type C = A | B;

function foo(fromOrTo: C) {
    const result = fromOrTo.from || fromOrTo.to
    // Get error: "from" or "to" don't exist in C
}
```

I know another way to implement this:

```js
interface C {
    from?: string,
    to?: string,
    items: number[],
}

function foo(fromOrTo: C) {
    const result = fromOrTo.from || fromOrTo.to;
    //  This is a one of solutions.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to check for the existence of the property you are interested in, and maintain type-safety downstream

```
interface A {
    from: string,
    items: number[],
}

interface B {
    to: string,
    items: number[],
}

type C = A | B;

function isFrom(fromOrTo: C): fromOrTo is A {
    return (fromOrTo as A).from !== undefined
}
function isTo(fromOrTo: C): fromOrTo is B {
    return (fromOrTo as B).to !== undefined
}

function someFn() {
    if (isFrom(fromOrTo)) {
        fromOrTo // Type 'A'
    }
    else {
        fromOrTo // Type 'B'
    }
}

function foo(fromOrTo: C) {
    const result = isFrom(fromOrTo) ? fromOrTo.from : fromOrTo.to
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20TKAewFsAuZAZzClAHMAaHPYSYi8kAV2ICNoBtALqMAvliyhIsRCgBCmJrjCFyVGiAaLkLCGw7c%20UIaPFgAngAcUAYWQBeNMgA%20yWQG5xMTiARhghEG0KADEiYgAKAhIAeSgAFRVkawBKcijiWISgx2w8ZCgIME4oQMiwzMJkOAo0ZIA6dOQAQjsHbwATCBhQCHasMS8fPwCghLKY%20MSUtPLJ7PlcvAKikuRxjLnq13rlZtbkDq6evrEsQd9-QJhCQnWK8hSFPIQAqnyICk4AGzB7INCSHdJslkAB%20fCzBINMLIGYTKHKfpAA)